# Emacs: default dir for (interactive "f")

Tags: emacs, elisp

I am writing a simple hacky solution to switch between «projects» (sets of buffers and frames (X windows)) on top of DesktopAid.  I made a procedure to write a project file:

```
(defun project-save-as (project-filename)
  "Save the current session to a new project session file."
  (interactive "FProject file to write: ")
  (copy-file project-default project-filename t)
  ; New project is the new current project.
  (write-cur-project-file project-filename)
  (set-variable 'cur-project-filename project-filename)
  (copy-file cur-project-filename project-default t)
 )
```

But it's annoying to navigate to the directory with project files each time.  Is there a way to set a default directory for `(interactive)` without altering global variables?

**Update**: here is my (somewhat silly) code, if anybody is interested → http://paste.lisp.org/display/129116

Comment: There's already `eproject` and `perspective`, which do similar stuff.

Comment: @Tass: there are other `(interactive "f")` to which I could apply this knowledge

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can easily roll your own `interactive` functionality, by passing it a form which evaluates to the list of arguments for your function.

In this case you could call `read-file-name` directly with a hard-coded default directory argument if you wanted to avoid creating a new variable (although it does seem like the sort of thing that you *would* use a variable for).

e.g.:

```el
(interactive
  (list (read-file-name "Project file to write: " "~/")))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!  Worked perfectly.