# Adding a file-exists-p condition inside an interactive list of a function

Tags: emacs

I'm having difficulty trying to add an if `file-exists-p` condition inside the interactive list of this print-to-pdf function.  The error message is:  `file-name-sans-extension: Wrong type argument: stringp, t`.  I have commented out the section that works, but which nevertheless overwrites an existing file without prompting for a yes or no.  I've tried replacing `hello-world` with `pdf-file-name`, but that didn't fix the error.

Emacs Trunk developer build --with-ns on OSX, using `ns-read-file-name`, likes to overwrite files without prompting unless an additional `file-exists-p` is included in the function.

```lisp
(defun print-to-pdf (pdf-file-name)
  "Print the current file to the given file."

;; (interactive (list (ns-read-file-name "Write PDF file: " "~/" nil ".pdf")

(interactive (list 

 (let ((hello-world (ns-read-file-name "Write PDF file: " "~/" nil ".pdf")))
            (if (file-exists-p hello-world)
                (or (yes-or-no-p (format "File %s exists. Save anyway? " hello-world))
                (error ""))))

))


  (let (
    (ps-file-name (concat (file-name-sans-extension pdf-file-name) ".ps"))
    (wbuf (generate-new-buffer "*Wrapped*"))
    (sbuf (current-buffer)))
    (jit-lock-fontify-now)
    (save-current-buffer
    (set-buffer wbuf)
    (insert-buffer sbuf)
    (longlines-mode t)
    (harden-newlines)
    (message (buffer-name sbuf))
    (spool-buffer-given-name (buffer-name sbuf))
    (kill-buffer wbuf)
    (switch-to-buffer "*PostScript*")
    (write-file ps-file-name)
    (kill-buffer (current-buffer)))
    (call-process "/usr/local/bin/ps2pdf14" nil nil nil ps-file-name pdf-file-name)
    (delete-file ps-file-name)
    (message "PDF saved to %s" pdf-file-name))
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why do you want to add it to `interactive` in the first place? Wouldn't something like this work for you?

```lisp
(defun print-to-pdf (pdf-file-name)
  "Print the current buffer to the given file as PDF."
  (interactive (list (ns-read-file-name "Write PDF file: " "~/" nil ".pdf")))
  (when (and pdf-file-name
             (or (not (file-exists-p pdf-file-name))
                 (yes-or-no-p "File exists. Overwrite? ")))
    (let ((ps-file-name (concat (file-name-sans-extension pdf-file-name) ".ps"))
          (wbuf (generate-new-buffer "*Wrapped*"))
          (sbuf (current-buffer)))
      (jit-lock-fontify-now)
      (save-current-buffer
        (set-buffer wbuf)
        (insert-buffer sbuf)
        (longlines-mode t)
        (harden-newlines)
        (message (buffer-name sbuf))
        (spool-buffer-given-name (buffer-name sbuf))
        (kill-buffer wbuf)
        (switch-to-buffer "*PostScript*")
        (write-file ps-file-name)
        (kill-buffer (current-buffer)))
      (call-process "/usr/local/bin/ps2pdf14" nil nil nil ps-file-name pdf-file-name)
      (delete-file ps-file-name)
      (message "PDF saved to %s" pdf-file-name))))
```

Comment: FWrite doesn't bring up the directory panel on OSX with a keyboard shortcut assigned to the function.

Comment: I'll try a combination of what you just added, plus `(interactive (list (ns-read-file-name "Write PDF file: " "~/" nil ".pdf")`, which will probably work.  I'll report back soon . . . .

Comment: Yes, that works perfectly!   Thank you so very much -- greatly appreciated !!!  :)  I hadn't seen this type of a `when` example before -- I learned something new today.

Comment: I've edited the answer to use your `(ns-read-file-name...)` inside `interactive`.

Comment: Thanks -- I've added a link forward to your prior revision of print-to-pdf so that search engine users can easily follow the evolution.